# Django: Loading large JSON dataset with loaddata

Tags: django

I'm trying to load a large dataset of about 76K entries from a JSON file generated by the dumpdata command and after a while the process exits with only "Killed" as error message ..

What do ?

No I can split the dataset by app .. all the heavy data is contained within a single table.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that resource limits are killing the load before it's complete. If you can access the database remotely then you can set up the Django project on a local machine pointed at the remote database, and perform the `loaddata` there.